# Hiding a Table Row

Tags: jquery, html

So here's the scenario.

I imported a set of data from an XML file to monitor the status of printers and formatted it in a table.

Now, I want to make a series of buttons (or checkboxes) that, when clicked, hide the corresponding table row. I've tried several methods and none of them have been able to work.

Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th, td {
padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","runningprinters.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table><tr><th>Printer</th><th>Status</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("printer");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");


</script>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "check1">1104 Down<br/>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "check2">2102 Down<br/>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "check3">2103 Down<br/>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "check4">2112 Down<br/>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "check5">2120 Down<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

So the checkboxes should hide the corresponding row in the table. Been stuck on it for a few days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have an example xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample XML like

```
<printers>
<printer>
    <name>1104</name>
    <status>online</status>
</printer>

<printer>
    <name>2102</name>
    <status>online</status>
</printer>

<printer>
    <name>2103</name>
    <status>online</status>
</printer>

<printer>
    <name>2112</name>
    <status>online</status>
</printer>

<printer>
    <name>2120</name>
    <status>online</status>
</printer>
</printers>
```

I than altered your code to assign the name of the printer as the id of the row. Using jquery I hide the row for the corresponding check box. Here's my example

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        th,
        td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "runningprinters.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        document.write("<table><tr><th>Printer</th><th>Status</th></tr>");
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("printer");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            var printerName=x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.write("<tr id='" + printerName + "'><td>");
            document.write(printerName);
            document.write("</td><td>");
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
        
        function removeRow(id) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
        }
    </script>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" onclick="removeRow(1104)">1104 Down
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" onclick="removeRow(2102)">2102 Down
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" onclick="removeRow(2103)">2103 Down
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check4" onclick="removeRow(2112)">2112 Down
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check5" onclick="removeRow(2120)">2120 Down
    <br/>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide specific rows, you could add an additional cell per row which handles this:
`<td onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';" style="width: 20px; background-color:red; text-align: center; cursor: default;">X</td>`

So you have a "close" botton for each row, which is easier to use than having a checkbox for each entry somewhere on the page.

Just replace `document.write("</td></tr>");` in the `for` with:

`document.write("</td><td onclick=\"parentElement.style.display = 'none';\" style=\"width: 20px; background-color:red; text-align: center; cursor: default;\">X</td></tr>");`

Answer (score 0):

************************* Post Version 3 *************************

1) I added a onclick function which passes the HTML Element Object to a function.

2) I get the table by element id.

3) With x.parentNode i get its parent element which is the >tr<.

4) With x.parentNode.rowIndex i get the row number of this table.

5) By using deleteRow function i delete the row with the x.parentNode.rowIndex number.

Please let me know if this did help or not...

```js
function myFun(x) {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(x.parentNode.rowIndex);

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFun(this)"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFun(this)"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFun(this)"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFun(this)"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFun(this)"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>cell 9</td>
    <td>cell 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFun(this)"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>cell 11</td>
    <td>cell 12</td>
</table>
```